# Selenium 2.0 API

Tags: selenium-webdriver

We have started off our Web Automation with Selenium RC and now reworking on it to change it to Selenium API. Below are the things which are tuff to handle.

```
selenium.Mouseover(xpath);
selenium.Isvisible(xpath);
selenium.waitforpageload(seconds);
```

Does Selenium API 2.0 support above? Any pointers on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify a language, bur I can only answer from a Ruby perspective, so I'm going to go with that.

Mouseover(xpath) is replaced with driver.mouse.move_to(driver.find_element(xpath))

```
driver.mouse.move_to(driver.find_element(xpath))
```

Isvisible is replaced with

```
driver.find_element(xpath).displayed?
```

waitforpageload has been removed. The click and nagvigate routines wait automatically now.